# In a Bootstrap table, how to change the row-height, since I have a data-formatter box in the row, that gets shrinked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want the row-height (space between two rows) to be reduced. Since I have a data-formatter box in the row, that gets shrinked.

Comment: Provide a fiddle, or some of your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the the height of td, row height will be decided by the maximum  height of any column.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td height="20">Key</td>
<td height="20">Value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Key</td>
<td>Value</td>
</tr>
</table>
```